# Coating a silicone mold in chocolate glaze

Tags: chocolate, glaze, silicone

I wanted to make chocolate-covered quark sweets, using [a recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QQkkWQUVJo) from Youtube. The recipe involves mixing 160 g melted chocolate with 60 g oil, then coating a silicone mold with it and placing it in the freezer for 10 minutes to harden.

In the video, the silicone mold gets coated with a brush, and it seems to work.

[image: video screenshot]

I used a 6-nest mold, and until I had reached the sixth nest, the chocolate in the first one had flowed completely to the bottom. I don't have a straight-side mold, but it doesn't look as if the decorative shape is the problem - if anything, it slows down the flow somewhat.

[image: own mold]

Are there techniques which will allow me to use this mold successfully for glazed confections?

Comment: The description on that video says 30g oil... Typo here, typo there, or oops?

Comment: Maybe your chocolate mixture is just too hot? Maybe you should indeed use 30g of oil from the video instead of 60g in your question? Maybe both?